# ember js subviews and didinsertelement event

Tags: view, ember.js

I'm writing an `Ember.View`, which turns a tree structure into a menu. I need recursion for this, so what I use in my view template is a `{{view}}` helper, which recursively calls itself to build a nested `<ul><li>` structure.

What I need is a hook to call some jQuery plugin to turn this structure into the menu. When I call the plugin from the `didInsertElement` event, the subviews haven't rendered yet. How can I run code when all subviews have finished rendering?

Answer (score 3):

Try calling the plugin within Ember.run.next() which should call it after the current run loop is complete... which I believe won't happen until all of the subviews are created.

Docs -> http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.run.html

Answer (score 0):

This might help in your situation, I [made a handlebars helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760733/ember-js-using-a-handlebars-helper-to-detect-that-a-subview-has-rendered/13857859#13857859) that tells you when the sub-section has rendered. By default it sends an event to your view object, so each of your instantiated views would receive an event whenever they rendered.